# Unable to reinstall packages in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

On executing the command `sudo dpkg -C` I got the following results -

```
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 nemo-data            File manager and graphical shell for Cinnamon (data files
 python3-apt          Python 3 interface to libapt-pkg
 python3-distupgrade  manage release upgrades
 python3-software-properties manage the repositories that you install software 
 python3-twisted      Event-based framework for internet applications
 python3-uno          Python-UNO bridge
 python3-update-manager python 3.x module for update-manager
 software-properties-common manage the repositories that you install software f
 software-properties-gtk manage the repositories that you install software from
 systemd              system and service manager
 ubuntu-advantage-tools management tools for Ubuntu Advantage
 ubuntu-drivers-common Detect and install additional Ubuntu driver packages
 update-manager       GNOME application that manages apt updates
```

I tried to reinstall the packages listed above, but I am getting the following message when I do so - `E: The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Is there a way to reinstall all these packages without reinstalling Ubuntu itself?

Update: Thanks to [Gagan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/482007/gagan), I was able to get some insights into solving this issue. Unfortunately at some point of time my desktop went off, and I couldn't load the GUI (I was not getting the login screen at all). Through some hacks, I was able to access the terminal.

Although, right now I am stuck again. This time I am getting the following message.

command: `dpkg -C`

Response -

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 ubuntu-desktop       The Ubuntu desktop system
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal The Ubuntu desktop minimal system
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk manage release upgrades
 update-manager       GNOME application that manages apt updates
 update-notifier      Daemon which notifies about package updates
```

Most of these packages seem to depend on `update-notifier-common` when I try to install it though I get the following message -

```
(Reading database ... 264324 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack update-notifier-common_3.192.30_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-notifier-common (3.192.30) over (3.192.30) ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.192.30) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debian'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--install):
 installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
```

I have `debian` in my system, but I am still getting the above message.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

This is a command generally used to reinstall broken packages.You can also try:

`sudo apt install -f`

Comment: I am getting the following message when I run the above two commands - `The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned there... and I got a huge list of packages that had some issues, now `python3-apt` package is a mess, and I am unable to reinstall it. When I try to do so I get a message getting `py3compile` and `py3clean` are missing.